I want to zoom and pan around on an Image. Is there any Nuget that can help me do that
A simple content page , An Image , I want to pinch to zoom, then move around in that zoomed in image. I've written my own makeshift code, using Pan & Pinch GestureRecognizers, but it isn't as smooth and provide good UX. Does something like this exist for MAUI?

Can you try this https://github.com/FreakyAli/Maui.FreakyControls/blob/master/MAUI.FreakyControls/MAUI.FreakyControls/Shared/FreakyZoomableImage/FreakyZoomableImage.cs

Yes , it's pretty close to the makeshift code I wrote XD , the pinch works fine, but the pan doesn't stop at the edge, the image stops halfway into the page, leaving a blank area. In fact at least in mine, I'm able to clip my image within the container bounds, and it doesn't't engulf the entire screen.

I plan on writing something for this the only problem is i am not getting the time to do this, If i do this though I will add an answer here
